# Do we really need multi-threaded JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I have recently heard about the [Web Workers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Workers) spec that defines API for multi-threading JavaScript.  But after working with client side scripting for so long now (and event-driven paradigm), I don't really see a point with using multiple thread.

I can see how the JavaScript engine and browser rendering engine can benefit from multi-threading, but I really don't see much benefit in handing this power to application programmers.

Comment: This should be a community wiki at the very least.

Comment: I agree with you that I don't see the need for it right now, given that everything appears to be event driven. But I could see the need for it if the paradigm changed.

Comment: You can can sandbox a heavy piece of code, to keep the 'main' window responsive. Anything that takes a lot of calculations before you need to repaint the screen, or some part of it, can run in a separate thread. You don't ever need it-but you don't need cake, either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wikipedia article actually answers your question fairly well.

The power is given to us developers so that we can specifically offload tasks that would be disruptive to users to a web worker.  The browser does not know which scripts are necessary for your custom interface to function properly, but you do.

If you've got a script that blocks the page rendering for 10 seconds but isn't necessary for the website to function, you could offload it to a web worker. Doing so allows your users to interact with the page instead of forcing them to wait 10 seconds for that script to execute. In a way, it's like AJAX in that things can be injected in after the interface loads so as to not delay users' interaction.

Comment: where can i get the link for this `wiki` i can't find it

Comment: I see your point, but the only computational intensive task I can think of is rendering 3D...which should be off-loaded to the engine itself.

Comment: can applicationCache updates be handed off to a shared web worker? It blocks the browser for the duration of the update.

Comment: @lightblade There's a bunch of processing that can be handed off to workers but not to the browser engine itself.  Image processing operations, processing of large amounts of JSON or other data (e.g. read http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/03/nocomply/ ), audio sample synthesis, fluid dynamics simulations, that sort of thing.